# How to understand the macro of ACC_MODE?

Tags: c, kernel

the codes is:

```
#define O_ACCMODE       00000003
#define ACC_MODE(x) ("\000\004\002\006"[(x)&O_ACCMODE])
```

How to understand it? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The macro implements the function

```
(x % 4) == 0   --> (char)0
(x % 4) == 1   --> (char)4
(x % 4) == 2   --> (char)2
(x % 4) == 3   --> (char)6
```

It uses bitwise and operation to nullify all bits in `x` except the two least significant (this is equivalent to x % 4). And then uses result as index to extract value from char array.

The equivalent code is

```
char ACC_MODES[] = {'\000', '\004', '\002', '\006'} // array of 4 chars
#define O_ACCMODE 00000003
#define USE_LOWEST_TWO_BITS(x) ((x)&O_ACCMODE) // masks (that is sets to zero) all bits except two lest significant, the equivalent operation is (x % 4)
#define ACC_MODE(x) (ACC_MODES[USE_LOWEST_TWO_BITS(x)])
```

Answer (score 4):

`"\000\004\002\006"` defines array of 4 bytes/chars, we can replace it with:

`char array[4] = {0, 4, 2, 6};`

x&3 means - get only far right 2 bits in integer, basically it is equivalent of `x%4`

so, this macro do: `array[ x % 4 ]` - takes proper value based on index